# ENOENT: no such file or directory when running fs.readFile

Tags: javascript, node.js, readfile, fs, enoent

Since starting my project I am having a difficulty with reading from file. I tried both with relative and absolute path. Tried both creating my own file and using `fs.writeFileSync()` to output one.

Interestingly `fs.writeFileSync()` works (file gets created with its content), but `fs.readFile()` can't find the file it created.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var content;
fs.writeFileSync('output.txt', 'test data', 'utf8');
fs.readFile('‎⁨output.txt', function read(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    content = data;
});
console.log(content);
```

Running the script produces error:

```
$ node script.js 
undefined
/path/to/project/script.js:6
        throw err;
        ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '‎⁨output.txt'
```

The access rights seem to be correct:

```
$ ls -l
total 104
-rw-r--r--  1 myusername  staff    634 Jan  3 14:24 script.js
-rw-r--r--  1 myusername  staff      8 Jan  3 14:23 output.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some (unprintable) characters prefixing the `output.txt` string in your call to `fs.readFile()`, which are causing the problem.

In my editor, I'm seeing this:

```
fs.readFile('<200e>⁨output.txt', function read(err, data)
```

*"left-to-right mark (U+200E)"*

Comment: Indeed there was something and my editor wasn't showing it, also it solved my problem